# Include HTML File in Eclipse Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, html, eclipse, web-services, path

I know there has to be a simple answer to this, but Google's not helping at the moment.  I've got a dynamic web project in Eclipse which is using Java/Jersey to run a web service. All my java resources are called in a URI like `projectname/test/statistics`, etc. for different resources. My hangup is on a relatively simple point:
How do I include an HTML file in this project?
I'm planning to have this file as a sort of 'home page', in order to handle logins, etc. I'd like the URI to be something like `projectname/` or `projectname/login`, but I can't seem to find where I can define the path to reference the HTML file. Is there something I need to add to the HTML itself, or is it a setting in the Eclipse project?

**Update:**
Soo... I still can't run my html file through eclipse.  What I have to do right now is deploy a war to Tomcat without the html, then put the html file in a completely separate folder to run it.  This means that I have to type a different context root whenever I call my file.

Comment: By the way, I've already tried adding it to the build path. Unfortunately, it's not that simple. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My workaround:
Since I haven't been able to get this working directly in Eclipse, I've been placing my html page manually in the directory where my service is deployed to Tomcat. Placing it in the ROOT folder lets me hit the page at `localhost:8080/login.html`, and I can deploy it to other folders, say Test, to hit it at `localhost:8080/Test/login.html`, but due to my security settings (at the moment), I cannot place it in the same folder as the rest of my deployed project.

Answer (score 13):

I solved this problem by changing web.xml from:

`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

to

`<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>`

And then `http://servername/MyWebApp` launched index.html correctly.

Comment: man, this answer saved me... two days trying a solution without sucess.

Answer (score 10):

If you created your project in Eclipse, you probably have a WebContent folder off of the root of your project.  Files placed in there will be served relative to your project's context root.

For example, if your context root is `MyWebApp`, and you put the file `hello.html` into the WebContent folder, you can see your file at `http://servername/MyWebApp/hello.html`.

Your context root can be found/changed by going to the project properties and selecting "Web Project Settings".

Comment: Do you have a server defined?  Is your project published to the server?

Comment: Yep. I'm running on Tomcat 6.0. I've got everything else running from `http://localhost:8080/contextroot/otherresources` except for this html file...

Comment: What happens when you go to the URL of the html file?  404?

Comment: Yep. It's as if I just typed `asdlghasdgasgasdgdsa` after the context root (which I actually did and got the same 404).

Comment: Oh, and thanks for actually following up on this. I don't see too many people who do follow up, so I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sounds like you are setup correctly. Anything in the Tomcat error log?

Comment: Can you post the actual file name, context root, and URL you are using?

Comment: I would, but it's business sensitive, so I can't post the actual context root, but otherwise I'm running `http://localhost:8080/{mycontextroot}/login.html`, which should be the right URL. I've also tried `{context}/WebContent/login.html` to no avail. It doesn't seem like this should be so complicated...

Comment: It shouldn't be :).  Have you defined the server within Eclipse and are running the project in the workspace? Or are you creating a .war and publishing it to Tomcat manually?

Comment: I'm running within Eclipse. I've gotten the html to work before using a war I'd deployed before and placing the html file in the ROOT folder, but I'm looking to actually integrate the html to the project, so I'm trying to get this to work in Eclipse. Again, everything else is working in the workspace aside from this one file.

Comment: @ZKSteffel I am facing the same problem. Have you come up with a solution for it?